# select max and min value from a sequence from datatable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to get the Max value from a datatable using LINQ query.

```
var maxVal  =(from rowmax in datatable.AsEnumerable()
               where rowmax.Field<string>(column name A)=="1000"
               && rowmax.Field<string>(column name B)=="36"
              select rowmax.Field<string>(column name C)).Max();
```

I have the values in Column C like (154.93445, 142.05789,110.45632 and 94.34623 and so on) which are smaller than these numbers. But when I am doing above query for MAX i am getting 94.34623 but not 154.93445. I want to fetch the max number which is 154.93445.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why is the columns type <string> when the numbers are decimal.  You are doing a string comparison instead of a number comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Max is being called on a string rather than a number, you need to do some kind of conversion from the string to a floating point type.

Comment: " you need to do some kind of conversion" like `Convert.ToSingle` ??

Comment: something like `select double.parse(rowmax.Field<string>(column name C))`. The issue is that the .Max() method call is being applied to an enumerable of string types, it needs to be applied to an enumerable of floating point types instead like double.

Comment: why don't you simply write that into your answer?